# CSS3 transform: rotateY and keyframe animation does not work in Chrome

Tags: css, transform, css-animations

Please consider this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/K6pmH/3/

Clicking on the blue box flips it using `@keyframes` animations and the flip side gets visible. After ~3s it is turned back into its initial position.

This works for me on Firefox (16.0.2) and Safari (6.0 (7536.25)) but fails on Chrome (Chromium 22.0.1229.94 (161065)). I'm on a Mac (10.7.4).

On Chrome, only the flip side is visible (with mirrored text). Nothing happens on click.

Any ideas what I'm missing?

Comment: Works for me in chrome 23.0.1271.64 on Windows

Comment: Maybe you are loading a cached page? You could try to clear it. (It works here too )

Comment: Thanks for the feedbacks, guys! Do you all have Chrome 23+ ?